# Deleting duplicate list items from a list of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists of lists as follows:

```
All_Data= [[['Chemical Name', 'Average Ret. Time', 'Maximum Area'],
 ['1-hexanol', 5.10, 2544937.0], ['1-hexanol', 8.69, 3798101.0],
 ['1-hexanol', 5.54, 2470679.0], ['2-propanone-1-hydroxy-', 1.97, 227607.0], 
 ['acetic acid', 1.962, 227607.0], ['acetic acid', 1.75, 38359423.0], 
 ['acetoin', 2.32, 478054.0]],
[['Chemical Name', 'Average Ret. Time', 'Maximum Area'], ['1-pentanol', 3.00, 24864.0], 
 ['2-heptanone', 5.54, 10027158.0], ['2-pentanone', 2.10, 858204.0], 
 ['2-pentanone', 2.03, 858204.0], ['2-pentanone', 2.037, 858204.0], 
 ['2-pentanone', 1.97, 858204.0], ['pentane, 2,3,3-trimethyl-', 2.84, 1775913.0], 
 ['pentane, 2,3,4-trimethyl-', 2.75, 807020.0]],
[['Chemical Name', 'Average Ret. Time', 'Maximum Area'], ['.alpha.-pinene', 7.00, 8190.0], 
 ['.alpha.-pinene', 8.729, 21582890.0], ['ethyl hexanoate', 9.47, 71863418.0], 
 ['nonanal', 13.93, 10301295.0], ['pentanoic acid, ethyl ester', 5.88, 19659678.0],
 ['propanoic acid, ethyl ester', 2.30, 8107638.0]]]
```

So the list contains 3 levels: There are three main sublists of the list named "All_Data" and each sublist contains a set of data in further sublists.
I want to compare the sublists within three main sublists independently and see if the first item of two sublists matches, I want to delete one sublist and just keep one. For example, in first data '1-hexanol' is repeated three times, I want to keep just one sublist:

```
['1-hexanol', 5.10, 2544937.0]
```

and delete the other two:

```
['1-hexanol', 8.69, 3798101.0], ['1-hexanol', 5.54, 2470679.0]
```

I tried the following code but it gives the error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable".

Code:

```
for i in All_Data:
    for j in range(0, len(i)):
        for k in range(1, len(i)):
            if i[j[0]] == i[k[0]]:
                del i[k[0]]
```

Please help me on this.

Kind Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you the problem: you can't subscript an integer.  **j** and **k** are integers.

```
if i[j[0]] == i[k[0]]:
```

Perhaps you meant to use them as the first index in a 2D expression:

```
if i[j][0] == i[k][0]:
```

---

**UPDATE per OP's comment (second problem):**

Ah, yes -- this is an old problem: you're shortening a list while you're still stepping through it.  The code doesn't work the way you want: every time you delete a row, you change the indices of the later rows.  First, you miss a row; second, your loop is trying to run through the original number of rows.

For instance, you start with 10 rows, with rows 3, 4, and 6 (of 0 - 9) having the same first element as row 1.  With j=0, you run k from 0 through 9

When k reaches 3, you find the duplicate.  You delete row 3 and move to row 4 ... except that the *original* row 4 is now row 3, and the row you're now looking at is the original row 5.  You pass that, go to row 6, and delete *that* one as well.  You continue to row 7, pass it, and then row 8 ...

Except that there is no row 8 remaining in the list.  Your loop depends on a generator that runs through 9: that doesn't change as you alter the list.  **k** is now out of range.

**REPAIR**
The general solution is to *mark* rows for later deletion as you find them.  When you leave the main marking loop, make a second pass to remove anything marked for deletion.  Again, be careful not to skip rows: either work backwards, or use a **while** loop and increment the index only when you *keep* the row.

Comment: Thank you so much Prune  for prompt reply. I tried and that problem is solved. But still I am getting duplicates not removed.
I said after the `if` statement, `del k` but it do not remove the duplicates. When I used `del I[k]` it gives an error "IndexError: list index out of range".
I am a bit confused about this range function.
Can we solve this issue without using `range`?

Comment: (1) That's a separate problem that requires a separate question posting; (2) read the posting guidelines: we need you to post code that we can cut & paste, which will reproduce the problem.  Include the *full* error message.

Comment: Just to check the point I'm trying to make, I altered your code as I suggested, and set **All_Data** to be your list of lists.  I do not get the error you cite.  Please post the minimal code that reproduces the problem you see now -- as a separate question.

Comment: I wrote the question as separate but it tells me I can only post one question in 90 minutes. 
`for i in All_Data:
    for j in range(0, len(i)):
        for k in range(1, len(i)):
            if i[j][0] == i[k][0]:
                del i[k]`
gives the error:
if i[j][0] == i[k][0]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

While @Prune has provided detailed explanation about the error in your code, I'd like to provide alternative solutions to your problem.

Basically, you can define a function `remove_duplicate` for your 2nd level array to remove 3rd level arrays based on its first element, and then generate your final result with `list comprehensive`:

```
def remove_duplicate(sublist):    
    seen = set()
    return [e for e in sublist if not (e[0] in seen or seen.add(e[0]))]

result = [remove_duplicate(sublist) for sublist in All_Data]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shizhz. Solved the issue.